# converting/Casting ISingleResult - List values to my class without Looping

Tags: c#

I have a DataContract like this:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Employee: IEmployee
{
    public Employee();

    [DataMember]
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<EmpSalaryDetail> EmpSalaryDetails { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<EmpPersonalDetail> EmpPersonalDetails { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class EmpSalaryDetail: IEmpSalaryDetail
{
    public EmpSalaryDetail();

    [DataMember]
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int GrossSal { get; set; }
}
public class EmpPersonalDetail: IEmpPersonalDetail
{
    public EmpPersonalDetail();

    [DataMember]
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm using Linq to Sql in my c# app which creates the below code:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.GetEmployeeDetails")]
public ISingleResult<GetEmployeeDetailsResult> GetEmployeeDetails([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="EmpId", DbType="NVarChar(32)")] string empID)
{
IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)   
(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), empID);
return ((ISingleResult<GetEmployeeDetailsResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

I'm converting GetEmployeeDetailsResult the result to a List and I'm getting something like this:

EmpID GrossSal EmpName

a11   3560     raj

a12   9760     kumar

a13   5670     selva

a14   3080     joe

a15   8900     fra

a16   5500     ravi

a17   7000     mani

I want to map this flat List back to an object of Employee class.  I don't want to loop through the List and create object for each class.

Is there any other way like writing a linq query again or anything else really smart.

Please give you suggestions.

Comment: fyi looping through the list and creating objects is exactly what a linq solution would do.

Comment: @asawyer: But the point of LINQ is to make code more declarative and less imperative so that we can just say "project this list to a list of `Employee`; I don't care how you do it, just do it." LINQ frees us from concerns that don't help express the intent of our code.

Comment: @Jason I understand and agree, just pointing it out to the OP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ISingleResult List values to my class without Looping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020731/converting-isingleresult-list-values-to-my-class-without-looping)

Comment: @jeffamaphone: That other question is a duplicate of this one; this one came first chronologically.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick. You didn't give us the definition for `GetEmployeeDetailsResult`, so you might have to throw in some calls to `Convert.ToInt32` depending on the types of `GetEmployeeDetailsResult.EmpID` and `GetEmployeeDetailsResult.GrossSal`:

```
var employees = 
    result.Select(x => new Employee {
        EmpID = x.EmpID,
        EmpSalaryDetails = new List<EmpSalaryDetail> {
            new EmpSalaryDetail { 
                EmpID = x.EmpID,
                GrossSal = x.GrossSal
            }
        },
        EmpPersonalDetails = new List<EmpPersonalDetail> {
            new EmpPersonalDetail {
                EmpID = x.EmpID,
               EmpName = x.EmpName
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried this but employees seems to be null.  How to handle this?

Comment: @Joseph: If `result` is not `null`, `employees` is not `null`. Guaranteed. Of course, if `result` is `null`, the above will bomb anyway.

Comment: I'm getting this error....Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2[ExternalInterface.GetEmployeeDetailsResult,CommonDataContracts.Employee]' to type 'CommonDataContracts.Employee'.

Comment: @Joseph: Well, that's very different than saying it is `null`. Note that `employees` is not an `Employee`. It is a sequence of `Employee`. It doesn't make sense to try to convert a sequence of `Employee` to a single `Employee` (can you convert an alphabetical list of all the people that you work with into a single employee in your company?)

Comment: I gave you a wrong example so I have asked a new "Ask Question" -"Converting ISingleResult List values to my class without Looping" with correct example.  If you have any ideas please let me know.  Thanks