# Converting ISingleResult List values to my class without Looping

Tags: c#

I have asked this question already ("converting/Casting ISingleResult - List values to my class without Looping") but I didin't give a correct example. so I'm repeating the same question with a correct example:

I have a DataContract like this:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    public Employee()
    {
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<EmpMonthSal> EmpMonthlySal { get; set; }
}

public class EmpMonthSal
{
    public EmpMonthSal()
    {

    }

    [DataMember]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Month { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public float Sal { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm using Linq to Sql in my c# app which creates the below code:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.GetEmployeeDetails"
)]public ISingleResult<GetEmployeeDetailsResult> 
GetEmployeeDetails([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name=
"EmpId", DbType="NVarChar(32)")] string empID){IExecuteResult result =
this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)   (MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()))
, empID);return ((ISingleResult<GetEmployeeDetailsResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

And the auto generated GetEmployeeDetailsResult class looks like this:

```
public class GetEmployeeDetailsResult
{
    public GetEmployeeDetailsResult()
    {
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public int month { get; set; }
    public float sal { get; set; }
}
```

I'm converting the ISingleResult result of GetEmployeeDetailsResult to a List and I'm getting something like this:

```
Empname  EmpID     Month      Salary

Raja    1   1   8000

Raja    1   2   8000

Raja    1   3   8000

Raja    1   4   7800

Raja    1   5   7800

Raja    1   6   7800

Raja    1   7   7800

Raja    1   8   7800

Raja    1   9   7800

Raja    1   10  7800

Raja    1   11  7800

Raja    1   12  90000

Kumar   2   1   200000

Kumar   2   2   200000

Kumar   2   3   200000

Kumar   2   4   200000

Kumar   2   5   200000

Kumar   2   6   200000

Kumar   2   7   200000

Kumar   2   8   200000

Kumar   2   9   195000

Kumar   2   10  200000

Kumar   2   11  198000

Kumar   2   12  200000
```

I want to map this flat List back to an object of Employee class. I don't want to loop through the List and create object for each class.

Is there any other way like writing a linq query again or anything else really smart.

Please give you suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting/Casting ISingleResult - List values to my class without Looping.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972198/converting-casting-isingleresult-list-values-to-my-class-without-looping)

Comment: While someone somewhere will undoubtedly think of something capable, methinks it won't look too pretty.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<GetEmployeeDetailsResult> list;
```

// populate your list somehow

```
IEnumerable<Employee> result = list.GroupBy(e => new { id = e.EmpId, name = e.Name })
                    .Select(e => new Employee
                    {
                        EmpId = e.Key.id,
                        Name = e.Key.name,
                        EmpMonthlySal = e.Select(ms => new EmpMonthSal
                        {
                            EmpId = e.Key.id,
                            Month = ms.month,
                            Sal = ms.sal
                        }).ToList()
                    });
```

Comment: Its working thanks a lot. I just added Distinct:            Distinct((a, b) => a.EmpId == b.EmpId, c => c.EmpId.GetHashCode()).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Use GetEnumerator. Fore more info https://www.dotnetperls.com/getenumerator

I'll explain you my case and you can take help from this.

```
List<File_Data> liFileData = new List<File_Data>();
        try
        {
            using (var dbContext = new DatavaultClassesDataContext())
            {
                //Changes for EU setup, Removed sub client id from param for sp
                IEnumerator<sp_GetFileListResult> fullList = dbContext.sp_GetFileList(clientId, fileName, archivedFrom, archivedTo, modifiedFrom, modifiedTo, analystStorageAccount,recordDefault).GetEnumerator();
                while (fullList.MoveNext())
                {
                    File_Data fData = new File_Data();
                    fData.Archived_By = fullList.Current.Archived_By;
                    fData.Archived_On = fullList.Current.Archived_On.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
                    fData.Client_Name = fullList.Current.Client_Name;
                    liFileData.Add(fData);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your class is corresponding to the ISingleResult, you can choose the Cast method

```
 YourModel model = DataContext1.GetEmployeeDetails(empID).Cast<YourModel>();
```

be sure your model is same as your function return result;